# wxPython i18n not loading

Tags: python, internationalization, wxpython, locale

I'm having trouble getting my i18n to load in wxPython. Here is my file structure:

```
locale
│  lembox.pot
│
├─de_DE
│  └─LC_MESSAGES
│          lembox.mo
│          lembox.po
│
├─en_GB
│  └─LC_MESSAGES
│          lembox.mo
│          lembox.po
│
└─en_US
    └─LC_MESSAGES
            lembox.mo
            lembox.pot
```

`lembox.pot` looks like this:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""

"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2016-01-23 23:27+GMT Standard Time\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: ENCODING\n"
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"
```

A sample .po file looks like this:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR ORGANIZATION
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: LemBox\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2016-01-23 23:44+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2016-01-23 23:45+0000\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.6\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: lembox.py\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-1: main_app.py\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-2: utility.py\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-3: hash_util.py\n"

#: hash_util.py:13
msgid "hash_shortcut"
msgstr "Hash bilden"

#: hash_util.py:16
msgid "hash_title"
msgstr "Hashbildung"

#: main_app.py:37
msgid "exit"
msgstr "Beenden"

#: main_app.py:45
msgid "LemBox"
msgstr "LemBox"

#: utility.py:21
#, python-format
msgid "LemBox - %s"
msgstr "LemBox - %s"

#, fuzzy
#~ msgid "Hash"
#~ msgstr "Hash"
```

In my code, I load the locale like so:

```
def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    locale = wx.Locale()
    locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix('.')
    locale.AddCatalog('de_DE')
    app.MainLoop()
```

And of course, use the text like this: `_("hash_shortcut")` (with `_ = wx.GetTranslation` previously defined, of course.)

However, in my application, all I see is the untranslated strings. What's the problem here?

**Edit:** I see literally "hash_shortcut", "hash_title", etc in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
locale = wx.Locale()
locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix('./locale')
locale.Init(wx.LANGUAGE_GERMAN)
locale.AddCatalog('lembox')
```

The `Init` loads the default german bits from wxpython for things like dates in calendars for example and the `AddCatalog` would normally be `messages` where the mo file is messsages.mo but you have called it lembox.mo

Alternatively, you leave

```
locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix('.')
```

as is, and put a copy of lembox.mo in the local directory and still use

```
locale.AddCatalog('lembox')
```